# Button debounce intermittent in Arduino

Tags: arduino, debouncing

What I'd like to accomplish is for the button to be called once after I press it with my fingers. Sometimes it works but there are also times it doesn't. Let's say I need to select from a menu. There are times that when I press down or up button, it moves perfectly but sometimes, it will move twice with a single press. I'd like to get that issue fixed.

Somewhere in global:

```
int debounceDelay = 50;
```

The code inside the loop

```
a3StateDownButton = digitalRead(A3);
if (a3StateDownButton != a3DownButtonLastState) {
  a3DownButtonLastDebounceTime = millis();
}
if ((millis() - a3DownButtonLastDebounceTime) > debounceDelay) {
  if (a3StateDownButton != currenta3ButtonState) {
    currenta3ButtonState = a3StateDownButton;
    if (currenta3ButtonState == HIGH) {
      isDownButtonPressed = true;
      // do what ever you need to do when button is high
    } else if (currenta3ButtonState == LOW) {
      isDownButtonPressed = false;
    }
  }
}
a3DownButtonLastState = a3StateDownButton;
```

The button I am using is very similar to this, almost exactly the same.
[image]

I only have a resistor connected to one of the pins but I forgot the value I put, most likely 2.2k.

So again, sometimes it's good but not constantly perfect. I'm also thinking that playing with the value of `debounceDelay` might affect my menu, which I remember it did. The response became slower when the value was increased. I think this is called software debouncing. Maybe there is something I can add to make it a hardware debouncing.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the button-press signal on an oscilloscope or similar? It might tell you how much bouncing and error to expect, so you can tune your parameters better.

Comment: I don't have a tool like that. I should save money and purchase one in the future.

Comment: I saw a hardware debouncing solution here. Is this good? http://dduino.blogspot.com/2012/03/arduino-button-debouncing.html

Comment: Why bother? You can definitely implement what you want in software. It isn't clear why your code isn't working, though. Here's a simple debugging trick: for each "transition" you see, print the timestamp and direction of the transition to the serial port. It's like a poor-man's oscilloscope :)

Comment: Slightly OT: I highly recommend a [Saleae](https://www.saleae.com/) logic analyzer as a cheap and flexible oscilloscope.

Comment: Thank you folks. I'll try it tomorrow since it's 2:30am here now :)

Comment: Rising Edge, Falling Edge your button is very basic. Some time twice is "you think press once but maybe push 10 time". Set_trigger_up( when first signal is appear) > do_something(hold data, some light show ) > Clear_trigger_up(so button is enablenow).